# How can I add rotation to the object in SparkAR?

Tags: javascript, facebook, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

How can I add endless rotation to the object in SparkAR in code?

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
while(true)
{
myObject.transform.X  += 30; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that:

```
const Animation = require('Animation');

const timeDriver = Animation.timeDriver({durationMilliseconds: 2000, loopCount: Infinity, mirror: false});

const sampler = Animation.samplers.linear(0, 2 * Math.PI);

yourObject.transform.rotationY = Animation.animate(timeDriver, sampler);

timeDriver.start();
```